# Dynamically getting/setting model-specific DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I am trying to set a data annotations during runtime. This can be set using the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` class but I am trying to set data annotations specific to each model. I am trying to get the input for each data annotation to be placed for each property from an XML file. When I have a source file from where I get the annotations for each property in a model, it is working.

But is there a way to allow the admin user to set the data annotations dynamically? Say when the admin chooses the model, the properties present in the model would be displayed in the list, and upon choosing the property, the admin should be shown the list of data annotation attributes that are defined in the current context (so that he can select it). Will this be possible?

Comment: Do you want to select all `ValidationAttributes` in referenced assemblies? It can be done as                                                                  `var validationAttriubtes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(an => Assembly.Load(an))
                .SelectMany(asmb => asmb.ExportedTypes.Where(t => typeof(ValidationAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(t))).ToArray();`

Comment: I've had to generate a list of all of the `DisplayName` model attributes before, which I used C# reflection to accomplish.  As far as *setting them* goes, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better use of FluentApi instead of data annotations?